# Export specific columns of JTable to PDF

Tags: pdf, jtable

I want to print my *JTable* content into a PDF file,

I managed to do that except that now I want to exclude the second column and print the other ones, any helpful guidlines please?

```
 for (int rows = 0; rows < jTable1.getRowCount(); rows++) {
                for (int cols = 0; cols < jTable1.getColumnCount(); cols++) {
                    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(rows,cols).toString(),cellFont));
                    pdfTable.addCell(cell1);
                }
            float[] columnWidths = new float[] {10f,1f,13f,35f,15f,25f,20f,15f,13f,
                    13f,12f,18f,13f,12f,47f,9f,47f};
                    pdfTable.setWidths(columnWidths);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by just putting 0f as the column width of the column that I want to hide !